# How can "To Field" (recipient) be empty?

Tags: email, gmail

I was clearing my email when I went to spam folder and found that I have received a email which was not sent to me(or to any one) there is no recipient.

[image]

How is this possible ?

Comment: clicking the arrow next to it, and selecting 'show original' shows the header. Its a great way to find out what is *really* going on

Comment: The from address is clearly fake. If it's sent by hotmail.com, then there would be a filed called "signed by: hotmail.com".

Answer (score 4):

Your address was set as a BCC ([Blind Carbon Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy)).